# Strange problem with varnish automatically reverts varnish.service file

Tags: varnish

I am facing an extremely rare and peculiar problem.

We use Magento 2 in many websites, which uses Varnish almost out of the box. We face problems problems, but they are rare and easily fixable.

Yesterday, we noticed something really strange.

The file **/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service** is reverting to its default form somehow, without us updating or changing it. By reverting, Varnish stops working (because on its default installation, Varnish is configured on port 6081, but usually everybody changes this to port 80). So the fix is really easy, but it's really frustrating. I saw that on different versions too, both 5 & 6.

Does anybody know if Varnish is autoupdating these files somehow?

Many thanks, I am at your disposal for further explanations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that `/lib/systemd/system/varnish.service` is reverted shouldn't really be a problem, because you should have a copy of that file in `/etc/systemd/sytem` that contains the appropriate values.

If you perform `sudo systemctl edit varnish` and perform changes, a new file called `/etc/systemd/system/varnish.service.d/override.conf` will be created.

If you call `sudo systemctl edit --full varnish` a file called `/etc/systemd/sytem/varnish.service` will be created.

It's also possible to do this manually by running `sudo cp /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service /etc/systemd/system/`, but this also requires calling `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

Have a look at the following tutorial, which explains the systemd configuration of Varnish for Ubuntu: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/installing-varnish-ubuntu/#systemd-configuration.

If you're using another distribution you can find the right tutorial on https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/#installations.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The real problem though is not technical actually, is that we create unplanned work - and we get an angry customer.

I am trying to figure out how it changed - if there is an autoupdate or smth like this.

Comment: Update : it worked as a charm, one problem that i faced was 

systemd[1]: varnish.service: Service has more than one ExecStart= setting, which is only allowed for Type=oneshot services. Refusing.

I solved it by adding "ExecStart =" without a value before the actual ExecStart

Many thanks!